# How to show that these two groups are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm having trouble proving that two groups are isomorphic. I am having trouble with both the homomorphisms and the bijections. How would I go about solving this 2 part question:

> 1. Prove that the group $m+n\sqrt{-1}$ for $m, n \in\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of rational fractions of the form $(2^n)(3^m)$ for $m, n \in\mathbb{Z}$.
> 2. Show that both groups from part 1 are isomorphic to the group of all translations of a rectangular lattice in the plane.

Comment: You should emphasize that the former is the _additive_ group of that form.  What have you tried so far?  The notation itself suggests a morphism to try...

Answer (score 3):

*Hint.* Look how the addition works in the first group,
$$\left(m_1+n_1\sqrt{-1}\right)+\left(m_2+n_2\sqrt{-1}\right)=\left(m_1+m_2\right)+\left(n_1+n_2\right)\sqrt{-1}$$
and now look how it works in the second,
$$\left(2^{n_1}3^{m_1}\right)\left(2^{n_2}3^{m_2}\right)=2^{n_1+n_2}3^{m_1+m_2}.$$
Is it clear that the $n$'s and the $m$'s work distinctly from one another?  Does that suggest a map?

> You want $\varphi(m+n\sqrt{-1})=2^\text{what goes here?}3^\text{what goes here?}$

- Is it clear that the map is a homomorphism?  If not, write the definition of a homomorphism, and look at what I wrote above.
- Is it clear that the map is injective?  What is the kernel?
- Is it clear the map is surjective?  Look at the definition of your homomorphism and write the definition for surjectivity.

For part 2, do the exact same thing as above.  In case it wasn't defined for you, the group of rectangular lattice translations is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.